# Find string from array

Tags: c++, arrays

So I have this piece of code that has given me some headache. This is a function. `names` is an array that contains names. I ask user input to `search` and then I want to check if the name contains the string from search. I don't know what to do and didn't find anything that helped me (i'm probably just stupid).

```
bool contains(string*& names, string*& search){
for(unsigned int j = 0; j < names.length(); j++){
    if(names[j].find(search) != string::npos){
        return true;
    }
}
return false;
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you need to pass the function find an array, not names[j], so changing *names[j]* with **names** works just fine. Also you don't need to make the strings pointers since you don't change them.
This code works just fine for me:

```
bool contains(string names, string search){
for(unsigned int j = 0; j < names.length(); j++){
    if(names.find(search) != string::npos){
        return true;
    }
}
return false;
```

}